# Shortcut or menu options to create a new function in case of undefined variable

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

In Eclipse PyDev, when I write a function's name that doesn't exist yet it gets underlined:

[image]

Is there any keyboard shortcut or some options in the menu to create a new function with the same name and same arguments, like the following?

```
def get_scale_timeshift(search_id):
    '''

    '''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically Eclipse uses `Ctrl+1` to bring up a context menu offering mini refactoring solutions for the line the cursor is on. This includes defining non-existent classes or methods. This works with LiClipse a fork of Eclipse that is integrated with PyDev.

[image]

Comment: Works great, thanks! Is it possible to avoid any keyboard shortcut (E.g. using the menu)?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, no.